# how to index categorical features in another way when using spark ml

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

The VectorIndexer in spark indexes categorical features according to the frequency of variables.  But I want to index the categorical features in a different way.

For example, with a dataset as below, "a","b","c" will be indexed as 0,1,2 if I use the VectorIndexer in spark. But I want to index them according to the label.
There are 4 rows data which are indexed as 1, and among them 3 rows have feature 'a',1 row feautre 'c'. So here I will index 'a' as 0,'c' as 1 and 'b' as 2.

Is there any convienient way to implement this?

```
 label|feature
-----------------
    1 | a
    1 | c
    0 | a
    0 | b
    1 | a
    0 | b
    0 | b
    0 | c
    1 | a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to replicate the behaviour of [StringIndexer()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer) on grouped data. To do so (in `pySpark`), we first define an `udf` that will operate on a `List` column containing all the values per group. Note that elements with equal counts will be ordered arbitrarily.

```py
from collections import Counter
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType

def encoder(col):

  # Generate count per letter
  x = Counter(col)

  # Create a dictionary, mapping each letter to its rank
  ranking = {pair[0]: rank 
           for rank, pair in enumerate(x.most_common())}

  # Use dictionary to replace letters by rank
  new_list = [ranking[i] for i in col]

  return(new_list)

encoder_udf = udf(encoder, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

Now we can aggregate the `feature` column into a list grouped by the column `label` using `collect_list()` , and apply our `udf` rowwise:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, explode

df1 = (df.groupBy("label")
       .agg(collect_list("feature")
            .alias("features"))
       .withColumn("index", 
                   encoder_udf("features")))
```

Consequently, you can explode the `index` column to get the encoded values instead of the letters:

```py
df1.select("label", explode(df1.index).alias("index")).show()
+-----+-----+
|label|index|
+-----+-----+
|    0|    1|
|    0|    0|
|    0|    0|
|    0|    0|
|    0|    2|
|    1|    0|
|    1|    1|
|    1|    0|
|    1|    0|
+-----+-----+
```